# contact form 7 file upload not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue in cf7 when I upload 19 kb file then contact form 7 file upload not working. it gives error website.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. while I upload more than 250 kb file than form submitted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not set the Limit to CF7 it will take default settings, default acceptable file size is 1 MB (1048576 bytes)

you can set Limit,limit:(num)

limit:1048576

limit:1024kb

limit:1mb

Limit the max file size acceptable. You can use kb (kilo byte) or mb (mega byte) suffix optionally. If you omit suffix, the number means bytes. Note that you can’t use a decimal point in it (i.e., like this: [file your-file limit:1.5mb]) and it will be ignored if it exists.

follow link for more,
http://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/

Comment: Mr. J  I did it. but still have the same problem

Comment: can you tell me which type of file are you trying to upload ?

write down your code here

Comment: pdf doc and docx here is my link please check this http://cubewires.com/careers/business-development/

Comment: I have Try on Page, 

Response :

Thank you for your message. It has been sent.

`{"mailSent":true,"into":"#wpcf7-f117-o1","captcha":null,"message":"Thank you for your message. It has
 been sent."}`

My File size is 3kb